# What is the advantage of declaring an array size using a constant

Tags: java, arrays

What is the advantage of declaring an array using a constant in Java? For example,

```
private static final int CAPACITY = 2;
private int[] items = new int[CAPACITY];
```

What is difference between the above code and:

```
private int[] items = new int[2];
```

Note: An array's length cannot be changed once it is declared. Why should I use constant then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because if the `CAPACITY` is used somewhere else, and in the future you decide that the `CAPACITY` should be 4, you don't need to change it everywhere.

- improves *readability* of the code
- easier to maintain

Compare:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<CAPACITY;i++)
```

Avoid *magic numbers* in the code when you can.

Many Java classes uses constants, `Integer`, `Character` and more classes.

Comment: You could also use the array length instead (for the `for` loop). But I agree with the other points.

Comment: @Tom I'd argue that you _should_ use the length here, instead, although I'd write it: `(for int i = 0, n = items.length; i < n; ++i) `

Comment: It was just for the sake of the example, there might be more clearer examples.

Answer (score 4):

1. you can use this constant for some other array
2. to make clear of why is this length like: `STUDENTS_MAX_SIZE = 1000`

Answer (score 3):

The difference is, if the constant is named in any meaningful name, for example:

```
private int[] items = new int[DEFAULT_CART_ITEM_AMOUNT];
```

and/or when the constant is used somewhere else, for example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < DEFAULT_CART_ITEM_AMOUNT; ++i) doSth();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can (indeed should) use a constant to replace a number when that number is likely to appear in other places in your code and when it is possible that the value may change in the future.

It can also be used to give *semantic meaning* to the number.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the question is more of "What is the use of constants?"

1. keeping code clean
2. ease of changing the constant during your development

etc.

Comment: constants very rarely save memory

Comment: but if you go adding hard-coding  same thing in multiple places, it is going to cost you memory is it not?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is readibility and maintainability . Using numeric literals makes code more difficult to read, understand, and edit.

However, when the intent of the numeric literal is obvious using symbolic constants can impair code readability.

Note that in the case of String litteral (or other Objects), there is a memory overhead when using multiple identical String literal instead of a unique String constant.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't usually need a constant for array length, because basically there are two scenarios:

1. The amount of items to store is known in advance and very straightforward, for example: `int[] monthlyRevenues = new int[12];` There are 12 months, it would be silly to do `static final int NUMBER_OF_MONTHS = 12;`
2. The amount of items to store is not known in advance, in this case it's probably better to use another collection, like `List`.

If you ever find yourself setting an array with an explicit length and it isn't immediately apparent why it should be that length, you've got probably some other issues which are not solved by refactoring the length to a constant.